# Как ASP MVC взаимодейстовать с контроллером C# из cshtml через AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

В этом коде cshtml формируется таблица работников. В конце каждой строки кнопка "Удалить". Что необходимо добавить, чтобы кнопка "Удалить" вызывала нужный метод в контроллере?

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Workers)
{
    <tr>
        <td><p>@b.Surname</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Patronymic</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Position</p></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" value="@b.Id" name="WorkerId" />
                <input type="submit" value="Удалить" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С jQuery, будет вроде этого:

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Workers)
{
    <tr>
        <td><p>@b.Surname</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Patronymic</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Position</p></td>
        <td>
            <button data-id="@b.Id">Удалить</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

...

<script>
'use strict';

var urlToAction = '@Url.Action("RemoveItPlease", "Home")';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table button').click(function (e){
        var workerId = $(e.target).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: urlToAction,
            method: 'POST',
            data: { id: workerId }
        });
    });
});

</script>

....

public HomeController: Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveItPlease(int id) {     
        ...
    }
}
```

Обработку ошибок и обновление таблицы оставляю за скобками.

Comment: Используя данный код, в строке
var workerId = e.target.data('Id');
возникает ошибка
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.data is not a function

Comment: @РыбаковГригорий, да, точно. Поправил ответ.